# Expresso Store with Grid type field

Tags: expresso-store

I've been asked to set up an event booking system on an installation that already has Expresso Store. I can set up each event as a product item, and let visitors use the quantity field to specify booking numbers. But I also need to capture information on each person booked. I can include a text field modifier, but I would need a flexible number of fields for an unknown booking number. Is there a way to turn the text modifier field into a grid type field?

Comment: did you resolve this as we have a similar need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing out of the box that would allow you to do this. You would either need to create an extension, use JavaScript or change your workflow around a bit.

In the past I have usually seen it done where you enter a single users information in a modal window then click an add another button which will add that item to the cart and refresh the modal window to add the next person information. This would be repeated until you added all of the people and you could click submit.

Alternatively I have seen this done where a user will select the product and quantity which will load a new page using the product form tag and repeating the product based upon the quantity the user entered. Then the user would fill out the fields as needed and submit to add the item to the cart.

Both of these methods work because Store will see the same item with different text modifiers as different items in the cart.